# Optimize stored procedure to call table just one time with different conditionals

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have stored procedure with alot of select at the same table but different WHERE and different INNER JOINS.

I have two types of select like:

```
SELECT TT.VOUCHER,TT.DATAAREAID,ISNULL(LJT.VENDTRANSID,0) AS LJT, 
       SUM(IIF(TT.TAXITEMGROUP = 'ANTICIPOS',-1*TAXBASEAMOUNT,TAXBASEAMOUNT))AS TAXBASEAMOUNT,  
       SUM(IIF(TT.TAXITEMGROUP = 'ANTICIPOS',-1*TAXAMOUNT,TAXAMOUNT)) AS TAXAMOUNT   
FROM TAXTRANS  TT 
WHERE... INNER JOIN...

SELECT OFFSETTRANSVOUCHER, offsetrecid, cs.accountnum, TT.DATAAREAID, 
       SUM(IIF(TAXBASEAMOUNT<=0,TAXBASEAMOUNT,0)) AS TAXBASEAMOUNTNEG,
       SUM(IIF(TAXBASEAMOUNT>0,TAXBASEAMOUNT,0)) AS TAXBASEAMOUNTPOS,
       SUM(IIF(TAXAMOUNT<=0,TAXAMOUNT,0)) AS TAXAMOUNTNEG,
       SUM(IIF(TAXAMOUNT>0,TAXAMOUNT,0)) AS TAXAMOUNTPOS
FROM TAXTRANS TT 
WHERE... INNER JOIN...
```

them retrieve data from `TAXTRANS TT` and they repeat it alot of times as I say before. How can I do to do only one select for those two querys to do only one call and use it with differents `WHERE` and `INNERJOINS` is that possible?

**UPDATE:**

I create temp table as comments below like:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##TGJAE' ) IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##TGJAE 
GO

SELECT
   DATAAREAID,
   TAXITEMGROUP,
   TAXBASEAMOUNT,
   VOUCHER,
   SOURCERECID
INTO ##TGJAE
FROM TAXTRANS 

GO
```

How can I replace my selects with it? just change `FROM` and deleting `TT.` from select like this:

```
SELECT VOUCHER,DATAAREAID,ISNULL(LJT.VENDTRANSID,0) AS LJT, 
       SUM(IIF(TAXITEMGROUP = 'ANTICIPOS',-1*TAXBASEAMOUNT,TAXBASEAMOUNT))AS TAXBASEAMOUNT,  
       SUM(IIF(TT.TAXITEMGROUP = 'ANTICIPOS',-1*TAXAMOUNT,TAXAMOUNT)) AS TAXAMOUNT   
FROM ##TGJAE
```

Regards

Comment: It's not very clear what you want to do... but the only think I can guess you need is dynamic sql or a view. What's the end goal here?

Comment: I want to use only one select for both querys... to call table just one time becasue that table have millions of records so I need to call just one time @scsimon

Comment: is it each time anohter where clause ? Is it each time another join ?

Comment: is there a common where clause on TAXTRANS that you are limiting hte records returned from that table in both instances?

Comment: yes that two selects repeat alot of times but they always have diffrenet where and join clause @GuidoG

Comment: No, there always different @scsimon

Comment: It's still super confusing... but maybe you want to select...into `#temp from taxtrans...` so you only have to do the aggregations once. Then, use this temp for your two queries. You can index a temp too if needed.

Comment: sounds good solution but index temp table? is that possible?, how can I do that? @scsimon

Comment: The same way you would a regular table. [Here is a good blog on it](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/12/indexing-temp-tables/)

Comment: Can you check my update @scsimon

Comment: Side Note: don't forget about `Group By` part, that is also different ;).

Comment: yes that is how you would do it but i don't see a great leap in performance here unless you can limit the inital select into ##tgjae to reduce the row count

Comment: "limit it", youre talking about using clausing where? @scsimon

Comment: Yes. That's what I mean to limit the rowcount